# setAclUser issue with msdeploy command line on local machine

Tags: iis, msdeploy

I am attempting to deploy a web application on a local IIS machine (IIS 8.0) via msdeploy.exe from a command line.

When I run from the command line:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" 
-verb:sync -source:package=Training.Mvc.Web.zip -dest:auto 
-setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",
value="D:\Release\WebSites\Training" -verbose
```

I get:

```
Error: A value for the 'setAclUser' setting must be specified when the 'setAcl'
provider is used with a physical path.
Error count: 1.
```

I have tried setting the setAclUser after the dest:auto, but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you considered supplying the local IIS website name instead of the path? That way the acl user is taken from the application pool identity.

Comment: @RichardSzalay That worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering my comment seemed to have done the trick, I thought I'd add it as an answer so the question can be marked as answered.

When you deploy to the file system the `aclUser` cannot be automatically determined, but if you set your destination to the name of the IIS website (which, tbh, this process was designed for) the application pool identity will be used.